# Review-possible bug?

Tags: support, review

While reviewing on the main site, I saw that the upper right hand corner showed me that there were $10$ posts that required review. However, none of the individual review queues seemed to have any pending material. I am attaching a screenshot of this phenomenon. Is this a possible bug, or is there an explanation?[image].

EDIT: The given answer in the linked question doesn't answer my question, as it mentions that many of these reviews are for $10$k+ users. I noticed a spike in the notifications after I crossed $10$k. Just now, I saw $21$ pending, and went to the review queue to find one item.

Comment: To clarify further- I refreshed the page several times, and yet nothing had changed.

Comment: [What is with that orange box?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16857/what-is-with-that-orange-box)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: That answer seems to suggest that 10k rep users have access to all those posts showing up - but I didn't get to see them (I recently crossed 10k, and I think the notifications became more pronounced after that).

Comment: Is the behavior the same now? Have you reviewed some items already?

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The same :(. It's bugging me to see numbers like 10,11, and then going to the review queue to find it empty.

Comment: It's showing $21$ right now, and I went to the review queue to find $1$ item.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your posts and explain there that it is not a duplicate. That will bump the post, users who see it might vote to reopen.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks- will do so.

Comment: No it does not suggest that you have access to all the posts, a 10k+ user has acces to all the queus. Please read the information that is provided more carefully. It gives several reasons why some specific items could not be available to a specific user. Also see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/why-is-the-orange-suggested-edit-button-insane

Comment: @quid: Which $10$k+ user? I am confused the wording.

Comment: Any particular one perhaps this information will clear things up  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/why-is-the-orange-suggested-edit-button-insane I edited in above too.

Comment: Before you got to 10K, you were shown the count of suggested edits only. After 10K you are shown the total count of all pending review tasks. As explained in other posts, this count is generally higher than the number of tasks available to you.

Comment: @quid: Thanks,..

Comment: I think the new duplicate choice is a bit better. The important point from [animuson's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233536) is that the number in the orange box is not calculated on a per-user basis (only a per-site basis), and is cached. In contrast, the numbers in the review page proper are calculated for each individual user.

Comment: I agree that the new duplicate choice is much better, and gives me my answer. Thanks.